# Upon mousedown, grab children's (numeric) location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle - http://liveweave.com/6RQOf4

I know I can use `$(element).children().length` to grab the numeric value of an element's whole list of children, but how would you grab a specific child's location?

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to learn:

[image]

**JavaScript/jQuery**:

```
$(".spectacle-contenu *").on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  $(".grab-contenu").val(
    $(".spectacle-contenu").children().length
  );
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" class="grab-contenu" />
<div class="spectacle-contenu">
  <div class="objet">première</div>
  <div class="objet">deuxième</div>
  <div class="objet">troisième</div>
  <div class="objet">quatrième</div>
  <div class="objet">cinquième</div>
  <div class="objet">sixième</div>
  <div class="objet">septième</div>
  <div class="objet">huitième</div>
  <div class="objet">neuvième</div>
  <div class="objet">dixième</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by location?

Comment: @jaakkoj He means the index.

Comment: thats not far. $(event.target).index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
$('.spectacle-contenu').children().on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
    $('.grab-contenu').val($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0apjynhn/3/).  You can get rid of the `+1` if you want a 0-based index instead.

You were using [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/), which is:

> Description: The number of elements in the jQuery object.

By trying to get the `.length`, you were getting the number of elements in the parent, not the index of the element like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Looped through the children and compared whether that child was the one you clicked. Returned the index for it.

http://liveweave.com/A0KcZC

Edit: Got a better way by using the `index` function passing in the `objet` class. http://liveweave.com/QGWbWV

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), I have binded event to `objet` element

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".spectacle-contenu").on('mousedown touchstart', '.objet', function() {
    $(".grab-contenu").val($(this).index() + 1);    
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://liveweave.com/ku0ipj)